# Filter in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a filter in powerBI that works like this for this kind of dataset:

| Column FROM | Column TO |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| B | A |
| A | C |
| B | D |

The filter PLACE() has the list (A; B ; C ; D)
when I click on "A" I will need to obtain a dataset like this :
Only with the data where "A" appears (either in FROM or TO colums)

| Column FROM | Column TO |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| B | A |
| A | C |

But I don't really know how to make this kind of filter or measure in PowerBI.

Thank you very much for your ideas :)

I tried making some measures but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think here you have at least two options:

1. Filtering by relationship

   - Add a new column in your original data that acts as a filtering key
   - Add a new two-column table in your dataset that contains the cross product of all unique values along with all actual combinations of FROM/TO columns along with the appropriate row keys
   - Use the column containing the values from FROM/TO columns as a slicer
2. Filtering by measure

   - Add a simple one-column table in your data model that contains the unique values in your FROM/TO columns
   - Write a simple measure that gets the selected value from the one-column table (the filter value) and calculate which rows are applicable in the visual
   - Use this measure on a visual as a filter

### Option 1:

With this solution we need to add a new column to our base data table that will act as a key to the additional filter table we need to persist to the model. Simply add a custom column in Power Query using `[Column FROM]&[Column TO]` as the expression to reshape the data like this:

| Column FROM | Column TO | KEY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | AC |
| B | A | BA |
| A | C | AC |
| B | D | BD |
| C | A | CA |

We will again persist a new table using DAX, this will be a two-column table that contains all the distinct values in FROM/TO columns, with all the corresponding keys  that are available in your dataset:

```
Filter Table = 
VAR _combos = 
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        'Table' , 
        'Table'[Column FROM] , 
        'Table'[Column TO] , 
        "KEY" , [Column FROM] & [Column TO]
    )
RETURN
    UNION ( 
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( 
            _combos , 
            "Value" , [Column FROM] , 
            "KEY" , [KEY] 
        ) , 
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( 
            _combos , 
            "Value" , [Column TO] , 
            "KEY" , [KEY] 
        )
    )
```

This filter table must be connected to your original data using an active relationship. We need to establish a many-to-many relationship but we want to disable bidirectional filtering, and instead want to have single-direction filtering where the `Filter Table` filters `Table` but NOT the other way around:

[image]

A small caveat is that there is generally an opinion that many-many relationships are scary and should be avoided, but this is a clear cut case where this is required for functionality to work. Moreover, since we have a single-direction relationship we are not worried about "weird" effects on calculations since we should have a very good understanding of why this many-many relationship is in the model.

Now we can use the `'Filter Table[Value]` column in a slicer directly to get what we want, without any visual level filtering:

[image]

### Option 2:

For this we need to persist a one-column table in the data model that contains all unique values present in FROM/TO columns in your original data. Add a new table using this formula:

```
Filter Table = 
DISTINCT ( 
    UNION ( 
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( 
            DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Column FROM] ),
            "Value" , [Column FROM] 
        ),
        DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Column TO] )
    )
)
```

Make sure that the persisted table has **no active relationship** with your data table. They need to be disconnected in this sense.

Next we need to write a filter measure that decides whether the row will be shown in the table visual:

```
Clever Filter = 
VAR _value = 
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Filter Table'[Value] ) 
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE () ,
        ISBLANK ( _value ) , 1 ,
        COUNTROWS ( 
            FILTER ( 
                'Table' , 
                OR ( [Column FROM] = _value , [Column TO] = _value ) 
            )
        ) > 0 , 1 
    )
```

We can then apply this filter to a visual, where you only want to show rows where the measure evaluates to 1:

[image]

And the result:

[image]

### Which solution to choose?

This is mostly up to personal preference. I would definitely use option 1 since I dislike visual level measure-based filters. However, I think it is always best to use the solution you **understand** the best.